# Parse.com - PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground() hangs

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfsubclassing

I'm having a problem with some code that I copied almost directly from the Parse docs. I *think* it is because something in the newer versions of Swift broke the code. [The docs](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#subclasses) say that you can override initialize() in NSObject, but when I do that the program just hangs when I try to execute PFUser.loginWithUsernameInBackground().

The code that I've written is attached. Even if I don't instantiate a Movie, it crashes once the initialize() code is uncommented.

I really could use some help, as I've relied on this code (without, I confess, a 100% understanding of its significance).

```
class Movie:PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var title:String
@NSManaged var year:Int
 //   @NSManaged var producer:Producer

//    override class func initialize() {
//        struct Static {
//            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
//        }
//        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
//            self.registerSubclass()
//        }
//    }
//    
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Movie"
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: There is no error in the Xcode console: all that happens is the button stays highlighted, and the program crashes. In the iOS simulator console, I do see one message ... Oct 18 19:35:13 Michaels-Mac-Pro assertiond[8751]: assertion failed: 16B2548a 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
and that's about it.

Comment: You should get an exception message.  Are you sure it isn't just hitting a breakpoint (blue flag in the margin) ?

Comment: That's a good question, but no, I definitely am *not* hitting any breakpoints. The program just stops, and the message that I was seeing in the console was what I wrote in my previous comment. Of course, now I can't even open the console, as it is crashing. 

Comment: It appears that overriding initialize() may be problematic - there was another report about this on stack overflow.com. I deleted the function, and use Movie.registerSubclass() in the AppDelegate, and that seems to have resolved the issue.